# Delete rows script on multiple sheets even when some don't have empty rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that deletes empty rows at the bottom of about 15 sheets every night after work is done on the spreadsheet during the day. I run this because empty rows are left at the bottom very often (but not always) and this helps to clean it up automatically without me having to worry about it. It works perfectly fine when empty rows are left at the bottom, but when there aren't and the sheet is full of data all the way down, it gives me an error and won't continue to the next sheet. I assume it has to do with the

```js
lastRow + 1
```

but I don't know how to change it to still run properly. My main question is, how can I still run this code as normal (deleting empty rows on listed sheets), but if there aren't any empty rows, it just goes to the next sheet instead of throwing up an error?

```js
// DELETE EMPTY ROWS AT BOTTOM
function RemoveEmptyRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId');
  var arrayOfSheetTabNames, i, L, sheet;
  arrayOfSheetTabNames = [
    "Sheet1",
    "Sheet2",
    "Sheet3",
    "Sheet4",
    "Sheet5",
    "Sheet6",
    "Sheet7",
    "Sheet8",
    "Sheet9",
    "Sheet10",  
    "Sheet11",
    "Sheet12",
    "Sheet13",
    "Sheet14",
    "Sheet15"   
  ]
  L = arrayOfSheetTabNames.length;
  for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    sheet = ss.getSheetByName(arrayOfSheetTabNames[i]);
    var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
  }
};
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to delete all empty rows below the data range for 15 sheets.
- There are several sheets which has no empty rows.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In your situation, for example, how about comparing `lastRow` with `maxRows`?

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows and try again.

From:

```
sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
```

To:

```
if (lastRow < maxRows) {
  sheet.deleteRows(lastRow + 1, maxRows - lastRow);
}
```

#### References:

- [getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for answering another one of my questions man! That worked perfectly. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: @Bryce Sinclair Thank you , too!